# Firebase database orderByChild().startAt().endAt() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data structure,

```
{
  "-LbrCWf6yUe1nr5iIn9O": {
    "mKey": "-LbrCWf6yUe1nr5iIn9O",
    "rank": 37477,
    "verified": true
  },
  "-LbrAMyMdwxSwwmEn_fn": {
    "mKey": "-LbrAMyMdwxSwwmEn_fn",
    "rank": 35482,
    "verified": true
  },
  "-LbqsgGcAMoh3YGkv1E5": {
    "mKey": "-LbqsgGcAMoh3YGkv1E5",
    "rank": 36484,
    "verified": true
  },
  "-LbrBXBdPMe-1Y_thyEs": {
    "mKey": "-LbrBXBdPMe-1Y_thyEs",
    "rank": 37493,
    "verified": true
  },
  "-Lbqqasv2t1R7jup1RSq": {
    "mKey": "-Lbqqasv2t1R7jup1RSq",
    "rank": 38500,
    "verified": true
  },
  "-LbqLO2eBnbRxHhHZb8X": {
    "mKey": "-LbqLO2eBnbRxHhHZb8X",
    "rank": 39501,
    "verified": true
  }
}
```

The requirement is to fetch all the `nodes` that falls within the certain **rank** range and the query goes like this:

```
RankPredictor_Ref.orderByChild("rank").startAt(35000).endAt(37500);
```

Upon execution of the query, zero `nodes` are being returned in spite of 4 `nodes` falling in the possible range.

I know, I am missing something here. Could anybody shed some light on me please. Thank you!

Comment: The JSON and query look fine. Can you reproduce the problem on a site like jsbin, so we can have a look at it?

Comment: Sorry! I was using variables for `rank` range and I was querying wrongly like orderByChild("rank").startAt(**37500**).endAt(**35000**); Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. Given that this sort of typo is unlikely to be helpful to others in the future, I voted to close your question.